# jquery selector all posible attributes list

Tags: jquery, attributes, components, loops

I want to list all possible attributes that an html control(be it button,text, radio or checkbox) has.
With help of this code:

```
var attrs = $("#mybutton").attributes;
$.each(attrs, function(i, attrib)
{
  var name = attrib.name;
  var value = attrib.value;
});
```

I can obtain a list of attributes where there are values. But I want more than this, I need to be able to list all possible attributes not only those that have values.
Thank you.

---

Having a page with some dynamically created controls I want to list all attributes (standard + optional) that a control can have:

```
$("#dropableDiv").delegate('.ui-draggable','click',function() 
{
    listAttributes(this.attributes);
});
```

However with this listAttributes method only a few standrd attributes are displayed(those specified when control was dynamically created):

```
function listAttributes(attrs)
{
     $("#at").append("list of attributes:</br>");
     $("#at").append("<table>");

     $.each(attrs, function(i, attrib)
     {
     $("#at").append("<tr>");
         var name = attrib.name;
         var value = attrib.value;
         $("#at").append("<td>");
         $("#at").append(name);     
             $("#at").append("</td>");
         $("#at").append("<td>");
         $("#at").append('<input type="text" id="prop' + name + '" value="' + value + '" /></br>'); 
             $("#at").append("</td>");
     $("#at").append("</tr>");      
     });
     $("#at").append("</table>");

}
```

for eg: in case of an input type button these attributes are listed:type,value,id,style,class.
        in case of an input type text these attributes are listed:type,size,id,style,class

Other optional attributes(which have no value yet) are not listed. for eg:size,alingn,alt,readonly,name,checked...

Comment: Out of curiosity? Why would you want to do that?

Comment: There are an infinite number of attributes. I could have `data-dog="sparky"` as an attribute if I wanted to. I suspect you are asking for all attributes based on a specific version of HTML. I would consult the doctype DTD for possible attributes.

Comment: Without knowing why you might want to do this, I would suggest its always a better approach to know what attributes/values you are expecting and basing your logic on what their values are / whether they are present or not.  Harder to account for the unknowns.

Answer (score 0):

here is a short code and [demo](http://jsfiddle.net/Xn9ky/21/)

```
var attrs = $('div').get(0).attributes;
console.log($(attrs));
$(attrs).each(function(i,item)
              {
                   console.log(item.nodeName);
                  console.log(item.nodeValue);                  
              });
```

Comment: I am working on an html page designer where you can dynamically create(drag&drp) various html componenta. I need to inspect somehow each dynamically created component  what possible attributes(properties?!) are so I can list them for the user to be able to alter their values at runtime.

Comment: ok so just change the div to whatever you want when you create the element. you can have this code inside a function that will pass the element or the ID of an element and than it will return the attributes (so just the $('elementhere').get(0).attributes) and than process them one by one as you wish. but the idea of getting all the attributes is in that code

Comment: Nir, it only lists these standard attributes: type,value,id,style,class. I think an input (button or text) gotta have more attributes than these. There are also optional attributes besides those standard ones. Such optional attributes are size,alingn,alt,readonly,name,checked, and so on. How to get these listed?

Comment: did you look at the demo ? i have there attributes that are not standard like attr1 attr2 attr3

Comment: true, but still doesn't list me those optional attributes (which I didn't specified when I created the control dynamically) However I would like to be able to set them later at runtime. So, can I list these attributes without hardcoding them?

Comment: take a look at this one http://jsfiddle.net/Xn9ky/27/ but i'm sure you would have figure this out if you took a chance and try it. I just hope that you will mark this as answered

Comment: i tried your example. I agree it lists an dynamically added attribute. however it's still not what I need. probably its not possible anyway and i might have to hardcode those unlisted optional attributes. thanks for your help anyway.